# What is a dispatcher?

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-web-services, performance, php-fpm

I have a wordpress site that was running slow so I signed up for stackify to get a performance profile of server.  I dont get the same slow down on baremetal and localhost running the same site.  This is only happening when hosted in AWS EC2 via Elastic Beanstalk.

Stackify reports that the thing that is taking the longest in the page request is something called "dispatcher"

[image]

If I deduct the time of that dispatcher then the page loads get to about the speed they are happening for me on bare metal and localhost.

I have googled this term and the closest thing I could find was a "cache dispatcher" mentioned.  I have disabled all caches on the wordpress site and nginx caching is already disabled but still this dispatcher is the slowest thing.

Does anyone know what this refers to?

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question in case anyone else has same issue.

The dispatcher appears to be time spent communicating with EFS (AWS NFS product).

Removing EFS completely eliminates this time.